# import mesh: format for array of polar coordinates

Tags: meshlab

I'm not a `3D modeller` and I'm trying to use a mesh plotter to visualize the output of a `sw` optimization which for every optimization result will give the parameters value.
I consider results to be used as Z-axis coordinate.
I'm thinking to use the radar chart principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart) to plot the value of the parameters with polar coordinate.

Example:
Optimization output array with 5 parameters plotted using this angles (0', 72', 144', 216', 288') as 360'/5: [z1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] , [z2, 1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1]
Plotting array:
z1, (0'@1, 72'@2, 144'@3, 216'@4,288@5)
z2, (0'@1.1, 72'@2.1, 144'@3.1, 216'@4.1,288@5.1)

The reason why I'm thinking about `polor` coordinates is because it will be easier to manipulate the results file for plotting where angles are the same for all the Zn results and only values will change.

At this point, considering all the above is clear, can `meshlab` import files with polar coordinates?
What will be the format of the file? Something like (angle,value,Z)?
Is there a way to give different color for each parameter and potentially gradients accordingly to value?

In my mind the  final mesh will be a rough vertical 'n-star extrusion' with lots of dents and spikes...

Please if my explanation hasn't be clear enough let me know.

Any hint is really welcome!

best regards

```
gipsea
```

Answer (score 0):

Meshlab can't import polar coordinates, just cartesian.
My recomendation is to use pyplot or Matlab/octave instead of meshlab for your plots.

If you still want to use meshlab, you have to convert your polar coordinates to cartesian in your program or using an intermediate script (python, bash, powershell) for that.